# How to use inserst ignore in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I want to have an error trap where the data will not be inserted into the table if it already existed. I have this code but it doesn't work.

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO staging_table (playlist_id,terminal_id,userid) VALUES
(
 (SELECT playlist_id FROM playlist_terminal WHERE playlist_id = i_playlistid),
 (SELECT terminal_id FROM playlist_terminal WHERE playlist_id = i_playlistid),
 (SELECT userid FROM playlist_terminal WHERE playlist_id = i_playlistid)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented under [`INSERT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html):

> If you use the `IGNORE` keyword, errors that occur while executing the [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html) statement are ignored. For example, without `IGNORE`, a row that duplicates an existing `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY` value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With `IGNORE`, the row still is not inserted, but no error occurs. Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.

Therefore you must define a uniqueness constraint over whichever columns determine whether a record "already exists".  For example, if you only want to reject records that match on all three columns:

```
ALTER TABLE staging_table ADD UNIQUE KEY (playlist_id, terminal_id, userid);
```

Furthermore, rather than `INSERT IGNORE`, it is better to use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) with an `UPDATE` clause that doesn't change anything (since this will only ignore duplicate key errors and avoid ignoring any other form of error - see [“INSERT IGNORE” vs “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/548570)).

You can also simplify your `INSERT` statement by using [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO staging_table
  (playlist_id, terminal_id, userid)
    SELECT playlist_id, terminal_id, userid
    FROM   playlist_terminal
    WHERE  playlist_id = i_playlistid
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  playlist_id = playlist_id
;
```